# How to fix stack overflow on overloaded addition operator in c++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I'm trying to learn the concept of operator overloading in c++ but I have got stuck on a problem that I'm trying to solve using the `operator+` where in the my main-function I add to userdefiend classes together. 
The class constructor takes a string pointer as a parameter.

My understanding of the operatoroverloading concept is that you declare a function in a class, using the keyword `operatorX`, and replace X with the operator that you will like to overload. Like if i would like to overload the '-' operator I should write like this `operator-`. But when I debug my code it results in an Stack overflow and the program stops.

The class looks as follows:

```
class Hello{
public:
    Hello(string str):pstr(&str){

    }
    //The overloaded function below
    Hello operator+(Hello& h1){
        Hello temp(*this);//creates a copy of the current Hello-object
        temp = temp + h1;//adds the new value to the temporary object
        return temp; 
    }
private:
    string* pstr;//pointer to string-object
}
```

I know that i get the stack overflow in the overloaded function.

In the main method i have the following code:

```
void main(){
    Hello h1("Hello ");
    h1 + Hello("World");
}
```

I'm not shore that i've coded this in the right way but the result should be `Hello World` in the return object if i'm not mistaken.

How can I solve this so that I dont get the stack overflow when the code is running, and also how can I get the right return value?

Comment: Notice that adding two `Hello` calls `operator+` which just adds the two `Hello`s, which calls `operator+`. You never actually define how the strings are concatenated. In essence, you've answered the question "How do you add these things together?" with the circular answer "By adding them together".

Comment: `Hello` doesn't appear to respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Copying a `Hello` will lead to undefined behavior, likely crashing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry on the compiling part. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @JulijusErgül With all due respect, you're not a better programmer because there is a pointer being used.  Why isn't it just `string pstr;`?  In addition, it would be better to overload `+=` first, and then implement `+` in terms of `+=`.  You would kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: Be careful though. Birds are in a general decline. We can't afford to kill them two at a time all willy-nilly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi, it was specified in the problem description that it should be ```+``` and not ```+=```. That is the reason why only wrote it, but you're probably right, that it should have been better.

Comment: @JulijusErgül -- Maybe you would have implemented `+=` correctly.  Then you would have implemented `+` correctly using `+=`.  Then you wouldn't have the recursion issue, as it would almost have been impossible to occur.

Comment: @JulijusErgül [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f57edd1b3b3e0eef).  Unless you were told to not create helper functions, nothing stopped you (it seems) from implementing both operators, and have `+` be a one-liner.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks! I will try to implement the ```+=``` operator also to see if I can solve it that way to!

Comment: I'm late to the party, so someone may have already mentioned: ` Hello(string str):pstr(&str){` seems a bit off to me. The address of a parameter copied by value will get invalidated (I think) once the constructor finishes. `Hello(string* str)` would probably work and `Hello(string& str)` will probably work (the reference means that it will stay past constructor exit), but maybe not necessarily recommended. This all leads to a bigger question, however: is there a reason it needs to be a `string *` and not just a `string`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in

```
Hello operator+(Hello& h1){
    Hello temp(*this);//creates a copy of the current Hello-object
    temp = temp + h1;//adds the new value to the temporary object
    return temp; 
}
```

the operator+ recursively calls itself, you have to *really* implement the addition

probably you wanted :

```
Hello operator+(const Hello& h1) {
    Hello temp(*pstr + *(h1.pstr))
    return temp;
}
```

Out of that, why do you have *pstr* as a pointer to a `std::string` rather than to have just a `std::string str;` ?

It is much more practical to have for instance :

```
class Hello{
  public:
    Hello(string s) : str(s) {  }

    Hello operator+(const Hello& h1){
       Hello temp(str + h1.str);

       return temp;
    }
  private:
    string str;
};
```

---

Note if you really want to have `string* pstr;` your constructor

> ```
> Hello(string str):pstr(&str){}
> ```

is wrong because you save the address of the parameter, you need to change it to for instance :

```
Hello(string str) : pstr(new string(str)) {}
```

and having a pointer you need to add the destructor to delete the string, and the copy constructor, the operator= etc look at [rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: I saw that to when I debugged the code but, don't really understand why?

Comment: @JulijusErgül _temp and _h1_ are _Hello_ so adding them call the operator on _Hello_

Comment: Only good reason I can come up with for pointers to `string` here is masochism.

Comment: @bruno The reson why I used a pointer is that it was written in the problem description to use a pointer to a string object

Comment: @JulijusErgül really ? so strange, in that case you also have to define the copy constructor, operator= etc and of course the destructor. Anyway my first definition of the operator is for the case you have a pointer to the string

Comment: @JulijusErgül your constructor is invalid, I edited my answer, reread it

Comment: Also should be mentioned that the compiler should have warned him that all execution paths lead to a recursive call. Or is it only Visual Studio that does that?

Comment: @Chipster g++ does not produce warning in that case

Answer (score 0):

In operator overloading, the key concept to think is how would the behavior be if the type you were defining was a primitive type. For example, what would adding a pointer to string with another pointer to string look like.

As mentioned above, your definition is recursively calling operator+.

Here is an example that might be useful: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of geeksforgeeks.org links lately, but I've never seen one of their articles that didn't contain at least one pretty serious mistake. In this case, `operator+` is not a `const` member, which means you can't add if the first operand is `const`. Seems like a big oversight. Any idea on why it's gotten so popular lately?

Comment: It's a very simplistic start. The first time one tries to invoke this on const operand one will get a compile time error.

Personally, I would recommend Stroustrup's PPPC book for learning C++.

Comment: I agree about the site being popular, given all the mistakes in the coding.  The other big problem is that the site seems to use `g++` exclusively, using default compiler flags, since a lot of their C++ examples suffer from the VLA disease.